# Python POST request data with headers

Tags: python, post, parameters

I am trying to send a POST request to this page:

https://url.be/fr/searchfor/

```
POST /fr/searchfor/ HTTP/1.1    
Host: url.be    
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/50.0    
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8    
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3     
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br    
Referer: same

Cookie: __utma=264609361.761154405.1479580795.1479580795.1479580795.1; __utmz=264609361.1479580795.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); PHPSESSID=290392ec3af681078222b6e40f8e6c9e    
DNT: 1    
Connection: keep-alive    
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded     
Content-Length: 68     
search_name=dubois&search_place=&search_place_min=&search_place_max=     

HTTP/1.1 200 OK    
Date: Sun, 20 Nov 2016 06:10:45 GMT    
Server: Apache     
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT     
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0     
Pragma: no-cache     
Vary: Accept-Encoding     
Content-Encoding: gzip     
Content-Length: 5554     
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8     
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=150     
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

This is my code, i already tried several solutions but i have always the same response: **400 Bad Request**

```
data = urllib.urlencode({'search_name' : 'dubois', 'search_place' : '','search_place_min':'', 'search_place_max' : ''})    

h = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.url.be")    

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'
,'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Referer': 'url',
'Cookie': '__utma=264609361.761154405.1479580795.1479580795.1479580795.1; __utmz=264609361.1479580795.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); PHPSESSID=290392ec3af681078222b6e40f8e6c9e',    
'Connection': 'keep-alive',    
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',     
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',     
'Content-Length': '78'
}

u = urllib2.urlopen('see URL ', data)     

h.request('POST', '/fr/searchfor/', data, headers)    

r = h.getresponse()     
decompressed_data=zlib.decompress(r.read(), 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)     
print decompressed_data
```

Comment: edit question and use button `{}` to format code (and other inforamtion) to make them more readable.

Comment: you don't have to use `'Accept-Encoding'` header and you will no have to compress data. Are you sure you data has length 78 bytes as in `'Content-Length': '78'` ?

Comment: your `coockies` can be wrong. Better first use `GET` and server assigns you new cookies - more important `PHPSESSID` - and then you can use it in `POST` (other cookies are use by Google Analytics)